# How to interpret the json response from the signalr connect request

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to integrate signalr with an existing asp.net forms web app.

After initially connecting successfully and the server side then calling back to the client js function, signalr seems to have trouble maintaining a connection.  I'm developing on a windows 7 machine so the 10 connections limit makes this somewhat challenging to debug.  I have however, seen what *appears* to be the same issue when the website is deployed to a 2003 Enterprise Ed. Server so I don't think I'm seeing a connection limit issue (I stand ready to be corrected though)

Looking in fiddler, I do eventually get a 200 for the connection request but the only JSON I get back as this:

```
{"C":"B,0|7,4|8,0|9,0","T":1,"M":[]}
```

I have no idea what this represents.  Initially when the connection is successful I get this (which includes the data payload I expect):

```
"C": "B,0|BK,1|BL,0|BM,0",
"M": [{
    "H": "notifyHub",
    "M": "notificationReceived",
    "A": ["[{\"TransitionNotificationId\":527,\"AuthorizationJobId\":53,\"TransitionType\":2,\"IsWorkShop\":true},
            {\"TransitionNotificationId\":528,\"AuthorizationJobId\":53,\"TransitionType\":12,\"IsWorkShop\":true},
            {\"TransitionNotificationId\":580,\"AuthorizationJobId\":61,\"TransitionType\":2,\"IsWorkShop\":true}]"]
    }]
```

If I could interpret the JSON in the 'failed' request properly I'd have an idea of where to look for the problem.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T:1 means you got a connection timeout. When using longpolling the connection will timeout every 120 seconds (by default). This is because most load balancers/proxies will kill idle connections after sometime. The other transports send a keep alive to stop this from happening.

As for the rest of the payload:

```
C: Cursor
M: Messages
   H: Hubname
   M: Method name
   A: Method args
T: Timeout
D: Disconnect
```